# How to integrate wordpress advanced custom field option show in frontend for registered users?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, plugins, frontend

I am using WordPress Advanced custom field Plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). It's very useful back-end.

How to integrate Advanced custom field option show in frontend for registered users for post submitted form.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this Advanced custom field's [Documents](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/tutorials/using-acf_form-to-create-a-new-post/) and follow steps...

You can create form for adding post from front side...

May be this will help you...

Comment: Thanks Akshay. This Documents Some helpful for me.